# How to make text in a textbox/validation textbox be confined to it, instead of overflowing?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dojo

Hi I have a  validation text box which gets data when a user clicks on a button. The data in text box can be continuous chunks, and this data is getting trimmed /hidden,that is data occupies only first row and rest of the data gets trimmed instead I want it to take up the next row in text box(400 by 100). How do I do it?

Comment: Can you add some code as well. Did you tried css word-wrap ?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question but dijit/form/ValidationTextBox is not designed to take up multiple rows or lines of data.

Comment: You can use dijit/form/Textarea instead, however it does not provide validation for you.

Comment: I have declared the text box as: var Wdg = new ValidationTextBox({ id:"Lid", disabled:false, value:singleCvlanValue, style:"width:400px !important;height:100px !important; word-wrap:break-word;", //validator:xValidate.isInRange, //constraints:{min:1,max:4094}, //invalidMessage:'Allowed range of values : 1 to 4094. onChange:function(value){ //Expand(this);

                    }
                });
But this did not help, I have used dijit/form/SimpleTextArea and that solved my problem. But have to deal with line breaks  while sending the data to xml.